# The limiting distribution of the central limit theorem

Tags: probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

As per central limit theorem(CLT)
$$
\lim_{n \to\infty}P\left(\frac{a\sigma}{ \sqrt {n}}<A_n-\mu<\frac{b\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{a}^{b}e^{-t^2/2}dt
$$
where
$$
A_n=\frac1n(X_1+X_2+...X_n)\\
\mu=E(X_i)\\
\sigma^2=E((X_i-\mu)^2)<\infty
$$

Here $X_i$ are independent random variables.

My understanding so far was that in the limit of large $n$, saying $A_n-\mu$ is distributed as a normal distribution, $N(0,1)$, was same as saying that $A_n$ was distributed as $N(\mu,\sigma/\sqrt{n})$ but the latter would tend to $N(\mu,0)$ or a spike about $\mu$. In other words  $\lim_{n\to\infty}A_n\to\mu$  . Is this line of reasoning correct?

I am getting really confused regarding this: "under large $n$, the arithmetic mean,$A_n$, would tend to the expectation,$\mu$". 
If this was true, there would be no distribution of $A_n$ at all, just a spike at $\mu$. On the other hand, the RHS of CLT indicates that the probability of $A_n-\mu$ lying close to zero is zero..

I have looked at texts and wiki but only got more confused. I hope someone can resolve this stupid doubt.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the limit of $A_n$ as you define it will be $\delta$-distributed and it can only have one value, its expectation, $\mu$. The right way to do it is to define $$B_n =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(X_1+\dots+X_n)-\sqrt n\,\mu$$ and then it will be distributed as $\mathcal N(0, \sigma)$.

Alternatively, if you like to be able to think in terms of $A_n$, you can interpret the statement as: for large $n$, $A_n$ is approximately distributed as $\mathcal N(\mu, \sigma/\sqrt n)$. It's distribution gets narrower as $n$ gets larger.

The moral of the story is that when you add up random variables, the mean grows linearly with $n$, but the fluctuations grows with $\sqrt n$. So if you divide by $n$, the fluctuations disappear, and the mean approaches the expected value.

Comment: but the RHS of CLT should  be 1 if $A_n\to\mu$. instead its independent of $n$ and depends on $a$ and $b$ in other words even for large n, $A_n$ fluctuates about $\mu$ so I am still not clear

Comment: @lineage notice that the LHS of your statement of CLT depends on $n$, so as you increase $n$, you are looking at the probability of $A_n$ being in smaller and smaller intervals, and you find that this probability is constant with $n$. Meaning that if you were to look at the probability $A_n$ being within a constant interval around $\mu$ you would find that the RHS would appoach $1$.

Comment: @stochasic oh no.. thats what I thought too but the limit is outside $P(...$, so the intervals need not shrink while taking $N\to\infty$. as $P$ is taken first. Moreover, no matter how small the interval, $a,b$ don't chnage

Comment: @lineage I'm not sure I understand what the issue is and why it matters that the limit is outside of $P$. It is known that for practical purposes (like in engineering), $n=100$ is large enough to use CLT as an approximation. This means that $P(a\sigma/10<A_{100}-\mu<b\sigma/10)$ is very close to the RHS. But so is this probability evaluated at any other $n>100$. For example, $$P(a\sigma/10<A_{100}-\mu<b\sigma/10)\approx P(a\sigma/100<A_{10000}-\mu<b\sigma/100).$$ You can see that the larger the $n$ the smaller the interval you need to take to get approximately the same probability.